Extend generic interface used in package
I would like to implement some automatic behaviors in RTK Query. Therefore I implemented some debounced mutations and would like to also handle optimistic updates before the mutation even fired the request. The implementation works as desired.
Though I would like to also get the Typescript suggestions right. Therefore I need to extend the generic type interface MutationExtraOptions provided by RTK Query.
However, unfortunately this does not work as desired:
declare module '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' {
   export interface MutationExtraOptions<
       TagTypes extends string,
       ResultType,
       QueryArg,
       BaseQuery extends BaseQueryFn,
       ReducerPath extends string = string
   > {
       optimisticUpdates?: { (args: QueryArg): any[]; }[];
   }
}

Where my implementation would look like this:

As you can see, the optimisticUpdates is not recognized by VS-code.

I'd assume that you need to
declare module '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/endpointDefinitions'

for that.

Uff that's great, thank you so much! Could you post this as answer so I could accept it? Also do you know how I make the draft to be automatically typed correct? I would need to replace the any[] though I have no idea how to get the Responsetype for the API provided in the second array parameter...

That's probably not possible - at that point, you're still defining all these apis, so their types probably won't be able to cross-reference each other.

Yes, you might be completely right unfortunately. I tried replacing any[] with OptimisticUpdateFuncReturnTypeGeneric<keyof EndpointDefinitions> and implemented type OptimisticUpdateFuncReturnTypeGeneric<EndpointName extends keyof EndpointDefinitions> = [ endpoint: EndpointName, queryArg: QueryArgFrom<EndpointDefinitions[EndpointName]>, transform: (draft: ResultTypeFrom<EndpointDefinitions[EndpointName]>) => ResultTypeFrom<EndpointDefinitions[EndpointName]> | void ]; however either this doesn't make sense or doesn't work as you supposed.

You're probably not enhancing the right path - I'd assume that you need to
declare module '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/endpointDefinitions' {
  // ..
}

like RTK-Q does internally.
